# Bind data to treeview node

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I am using a loop to search indexed objects and create a treeview from the objects that meet the criteria.

I would like to "bind" data to each node in the tree view so when it is clicked I can pull up the indexed object's properties.

Is there a way to "Bind" data to a treeview node?

Code I wrote to loop through the indexed objects.

```
Private ClanIndex As Integer

Public Sub TreeviewPopulate()
    Dim Clan_Level As TreeNode = Nothing
    Dim Enclave_Title_Level As TreeNode = Nothing
    Dim Enclave_Planet_Level As TreeNode = Nothing
    Dim Enclave_Enclave_Level As TreeNode = Nothing

    Dim _Planet As Integer
    Dim _Enclave As Integer
    Dim _Owner As String = Form1.GAME.Clan(ClanIndex).Clan

    For _Planet = 2 To 41

        For _Enclave = 1 To 4
            If Form1.GAME.Planet(_Planet).Enclave(_Enclave).Owner = _Owner Then
                Enclave_Planet_Level = Enclave_Title_Level.Nodes.Add(Form1.GAME.Planet(_Planet).PlanetName)
                For i = 1 To 4
                    If Form1.GAME.Planet(_Planet).Enclave(i).Owner = _Owner Then
                        Enclave_Enclave_Level = Enclave_Planet_Level.Nodes.Add("Enclave " & Form1.GAME.Planet(_Planet).Enclave(i).EnclaveNumber)
                    End If

                Next
                GoTo 2

            End If

        Next
2:
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Tag property of the TreeNode objects that you create to store additional information. You can either store the information you want to display, or some kind of reference to the object that holds these information.

For example:

```
Enclave_Planet_Level = Enclave_Title_Level.Nodes.Add(Form1.GAME.Planet(_Planet).PlanetName)
```

Can be changed to

```
Dim newTN As New TreeNode(Form1.GAME.Planet(_Planet).PlanetName)
newTN.Tag = Form1.GAME.Planet(_Planet)
Enclave_Title_Level.Nodes.Add(newTN)
```

Then in the event handler where you handle the selection of a node you can reuse this reference

```
Private Sub Enclave_Title_Level_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles Enclave_Title_Level.AfterSelect
    If e.Node.Tag IsNot Nothing Then
        If TypeOf e.Node.Tag Is Planet Then
            'Do something
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

(I assumed the class is called Planet. The Ifs are in place to avoid exceptions).